# Как в vector записать экземпляр класс и поток с++

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, **как в vector записать экземпляр класс и поток**.
Я не могу понять что я делаю не так.

```
class myCub {};
struct Cub
{
    thread CubStream;//поток
    myCub CubInstance;//экземпляр
};
void cub(Cub& objCub)
{
    myCub c;
    objCub.CubInstance = c;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Cub>cubs;
    Cub objCub;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        objCub.CubStream = thread(cub,std::ref(objCub));
        cubs.push_back(objCub);
    }
}
```

Ошибка  C2280   "Сube::Сube(const Сube &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию list-2  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory 696

Comment: *"Я не могу понять что я делаю не так."* - компилятор же прямо говорит - вызывается функция, которая не должна вызываться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, чтобы запустить поток, нужен первый аргумент как адрес функции : `thread(cub,std::ref(objCub))`.

Потоки копироваться не могут. Разрешается только перенос. По-этому при добавлении в вектор, нужен `std::move`.

```
class myCub {};
# include <thread>
using std::thread;
struct Cub
{
    thread CubStream ;//поток
    myCub CubInstance ;//экземпляр
};
void cub(Cub& objCub)
{
    myCub c;
    objCub.CubInstance = c;
}
# include <vector>
using std::vector;
# include <utility>
int main()
{
    vector<Cub>cubs;
    Cub objCub;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // указываем функцию cub
        objCub.CubStream = thread {cub,std::ref(objCub)};
        // переносим в вектор
        cubs.push_back(std::move(objCub));
    }
}
```

Comment: Самописный перемещающий конструктор не нужен. Компилятор сгенерирует его автоматически.

Comment: Точно стал не нужен. Искал ошибки, случайно добавил. @HolyBlackCat